# How to show scrolling buttons on top of page Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin.Forms. I need to show scrolling button on top of page. I have seen an example in Xamarin.Ios https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/scroll_view/create_a_horizontal_scrolling_button_list/.
I  tried this:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HeightRequest="90">

    <Button Text="Button1"   />

    <Button Text="Button2"   />

    <Button Text="Button4"   />

    <Button Text="Button5"  />

    <Button Text="Button6"  />

</StackLayout>
```

but with this code the button take up the full screen.Should I use Grid instead of StackLayout?

Comment: May I ask why do you need this design for ? why not using tabs instead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `VerticalOptions="Start"` of `StackLayout`.

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HeightRequest="90" VerticalOptions="Start">
    <Button Text="Button1"   />
    <Button Text="Button2"   />
    <Button Text="Button4"   />
    <Button Text="Button5"  />
    <Button Text="Button6"  />
</StackLayout>
```